# wijmo 5 scripts concatenation fails, anyone else found the same issue.?

Tags: wijmo5

Did anyone ever tried minified wijmo 5 angular js files?

I fails after concatenation, I tried putting all js files inside IIFE still it fails to execute.

Please let me know if any one has ever tried the same.

FYI: I do not have unminified files as wijmo provides it after buying licences.

Link to wijmo : http://wijmo.com/5/docs/static/references.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use CDN link for the same. Please refer to 'Deploying Wijmo from CDN' at the same link mentioned above. Here is the code snippet for using Wijmo 5 FlexGrid with AngularJS.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20163.254/styles/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20163.254/controls/wijmo.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20163.254/controls/wijmo.input.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20163.254/controls/wijmo.grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20163.254/interop/angular/wijmo.angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', ['wj']);

        // app controller provides data
        app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){

            // generate some random data
            var countries = 'US,Germany,UK,Japan,Italy,Greece'.split(','),
                data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                data.push({
                    id: i,
                    country: countries[i % countries.length],
                    date: new Date(2014, i % 12, i % 28),
                    amount: Math.random() * 10000,
                    active: i % 4 == 0
                });
            }

            // add data array to scope
            $scope.data = data;

        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
     <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl" >        
        <wj-flex-grid items-source="data" style="height:200px;">       
        </wj-flex-grid>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Manish Kumar Gupta